reading a TOML file with serde - camelCase vs snake_case
I am doing my first forays into rust and I am trying to see how configuration can be read in rust. I am trying the config crate with serde to deserialize the config into a struct:
use config::{Config, File};
use serde::Deserialize;

#[derive(Deserialize)]
#[serde(rename_all = "camelCase")]
struct DatabaseConfiguration {
  connection_string: String
}

#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct Configuration {
    database: DatabaseConfiguration
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    let settings = Config::builder()
        .add_source(File::with_name("config"))
        .build()
        .unwrap();
    let config: Configuration = settings.try_deserialize().unwrap();
    println!("Configured settings:");
    println!("connection string: {:?}", config.database.connection_string);
}

with the following toml file:
[database]
connectionString = "https://awesome"

The way I understood the documentation, the rename_all should take care of putting connectionString to connection_string but the try deserialize fails with
missing field `connection_string`

when I change the property in the TOML to snake_case and remove the rename_all part it all works, so it appears that I am misunderstanding how to apply the container attribute from serde.
How is this use case done correctly?

That's correct and works for serde with toml but config seems to interact with it weirdly. Or you might have forgotten to save when you applied #[serde(rename_all = "camelCase")]

@flq Have you tested locally with just using serde and toml, without the config crate, to check if it's parsing correctly before config could change something?

At the end of the day, this question might not be very useful in the future as it is related to a bug in a crate that appears to have maintenance issues - feel free to close.

You're hitting an open bug #522 or #5311 in the config crate, downgrading from 0.14.0 to 0.13.4 should work.

1) I believe both are the same underlying issue

Oh noes, how lucky can you get
